# Call native destroy method from flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have an app, and on destroy(closing) the app I need to perform a task, I tried didChangeAppLifecycleState method but it didn't work:

```
 @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
      // app is inactive
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      // app is paused
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      // app is resumed
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.detached) {
      print("app detached");
    }
  }
```

Is there a way to call the destroy native method from Flutter?